# Job advertisers that don't respond to applications and questions

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, jobs-messages

Job hunting is a pretty crappy experience when you apply for jobs or ask questions, but never hear anything back from the company.

Does /jobs do anything to actively encourage recruiters to respond to applications and questions?

I quite like the way AirBnB handles this, clearly showing the response rate and typical response time for each host:

[image]

I think this would make it in advertisers' best interests to respond to applicants, because they will probably get less people even bothering with them if their stats are poor.

Thoughts?

Comment: This would be really great, but how would it be conveniently implemented?

Comment: @snb, when you click into a job, there's a section at the right hand side with some company info and an 'Apply' button, which stands out quite well. Also at the bottom there are 'Apply' and 'Ask a question' buttons - I think either or both of these sections would be sensible places to put these stats. On the technical side, I would have thought calculating the values would be fairly trivial.

Comment: I didn't mean what it would look like, but *how it would be physically done* how would the SO team record those stats in a faithful convenient manner?

Comment: @snb Why not simply record the time the user sent a message to the company and the time the company responded to the message? I image the response times between questions and applications are different, but keeping track of the message sent times can't be that hard. The bigger trick will be keeping everything within the SOJobs interface, which isn't my experience when using Jobs. So much occurs outside of SO that this will be impossible for certain postings.

Comment: @snb SO must already record all the required data. They know who sent messages to *which* advertisers, and *when*; and they know *which* advertisers responded to each message, and *when*. I would have thought it was fairly straightforward to work from that.

Comment: @Andy exactly - and SO almost certainly already stores a timestamp for each message sent. I agree about keeping stuff in the SO interface, and AirBnB must have the same issue. But I think there is not much that can be done about that without degrading the experience. I think it's enough to only care about applications and questions send through SO.

Comment: I've never had to apply to a job on SO, so I didn't know what data SO had access to.

Comment: @snb Of course don't know what their database schema looks like either; but they must store who messages are sent from and who to - it seems rather obvious that they would store *when* they were sent as well.

Comment: @Cocowalla yeah, I agree they should have this data, or an easy way of getting it.

Comment: As Donna mentioned, we're actively thinking about it. However, one thing to keep in mind is that, unlike Airbnb, we don't have all the data. And this is because some employers use Applicant Tracking Systems (instead of our site) to continue the communication with the candidates. Others provide an email address and some just redirect to their own site. So there's no way for us to provide this for all the jobs on our site. This is absolutely on our radar though :)

Answer (score 89, accepted):

We recently ran an experiment that displays a "high response rate" icon for qualifying jobs. We're now preparing to graduate this.

We see this as a soft way to encourage employers to respond more often; plus it's a useful signal for job seekers.

+1 on Airbnb example :)

Comment: Sounds like a good improvement! But I wonder if some kind of stats visible for *all* advertisers (in an Airbnb style) might be more effective? Are you able to share any details of the results of your experiments?

Comment: This sounds like a horrible idea.  Serious employers don't have time to send a "atta-boy" respond to cheer up every one of the vast amount of dross contacts they get, in the programming field.

Comment: @Cocowalla Part of the difficulty here is that a lot of employers redirect job seekers to external websites for applications. Since the application happens out of SO Jobs, we don't *always* know if the application gets responded to.

Comment: @AurélienGasser I didn't realise that - I figured the 'Apply' button always sent a message using SO. Or do you mean it does, but that employers *then* ask the applicant to apply through some external website or process?

Comment: @Cocowalla The apply button either displays an application form directly on SO Jobs, or redirects to an application form hosted on an external website.

Comment: @AurélienGasser OK, then that's a pretty significant barrier to being able to know about the flow of messages

Comment: @Donna, What is a __qualifying job__? I was trying to search what "High Response Rate" means and this q/a seems the closest to an answer...

Comment: @Donna, never mind, it says when I click in the job ad: "This company responds to the majority of applications it receives"... I wonder if it was there before, or if I was simply blind...

Answer (score 10):

I would like to see the applicants for a job be able to vote a company up or down afterwards, and that score to be visible next to company.

Comment: I quite like this idea! Not sure if it would fly with job advertisers tho. I guess it could also be abused, so maybe the ability to vote on jobs/companies should be a privilege that you gain with, for example, 1k rep?

Comment: @Cocowalla yes I think your rep should help you get a job on Stackoverflow too. Maybe the candidates should also be sorted by rep? Something needs to be done to distinguish SO from every other job board out there and put us developers in control.